# Big Oh Notation of algorithm complexity

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

If N*C*(logN +N) represents computational time steps of Algorithm 1 and N*C*(logN +N*C) represents the computational time steps of Algorithm 2, then is it correct to say that both have computational complexity of O(N^2)?

*Where C is a constant value

Comment: Yes, it is correct to say that.

Comment: George thanks for your reply. If C is a very large value then numerical value of computational time steps of both algorithms will have huge difference. And still according to Big-oh notation both represents same computational complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here is my logic:

```
O(Cn(log n + Cn))
```

Remove constants

```
= O(n(log n + n))
```

Split multiplication

```
= O(n * log n + n^2)
```

Remove lesser term

```
= O(n^2)
```

It does not matter if `C` is "very large", we only care about `n` in Big-O notation as it is the growing term. When n gets large enough (approaching infinity for example), `C` will become meaningless. In practice `C` may make a huge impact but this is abstracted out in Big-O.

Comment: thank you for your reply.  Is there any method in complexity theory to represent complexity of both algorithms to highlight the effect of constant term for large C value?

Comment: I'm aware of the 'RAM model of computation' (http://www8.cs.umu.se/kurser/TDBAfl/VT06/algorithms/BOOK/BOOK/NODE12.HTM) which breaks down an algorithm into a bunch of operations measured in standard units, this method would take a very large C into account. The issues with this method is that it is so much more difficult to calculate. Other then that I'm not sure :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is correct, because f \element O(g) (*Landau*-Notation) means that your algorithm *f* increases slower than *g*. As both your algorithms increase slower than n^2, your assumption is correct.

Wrt the constants - let me depict this :)

Stating the complexity is *O(n^2)* implies the entire plane you can see from the nlog(n) to the n^2. That's where you neglect the constants. So your algorithm a can be far better than algorithm b, but still remain in the same Landau complexity, as this only gives an upper bound.

[image]

Comment: Thank you hannes for graph :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, multiplying the number of steps by a constant has no effect on the Big-Oh notation of complexity.

Also, the N<sup>2</sup> term dominates over the N log(N) as N gets large, which is what Big-Oh notation is designed to communicate.

Answer (score -1):

One thing to remember ..
The c values play an important role ..

lets say an algorithm runs  taking some 32 passes over an array .

So the complexity of the algorithm is 32*n = C*n = O(n)

lets try to run the algorithm on an array size of 30 . SO its 32*30 .Which is n^2 operations .

We generally compute Big O analysis for big sets ..Really big .so it makes sense

Coming to your question .

They both run in O(n^2) as long as your constants C are comparable .So that depends on the Algorithms

Comment: why down ...care to comment ?